# KDE Partition Manager versus GParted

Tags: partitioning, gparted

GParted and KDE Partition Manager are (of course) very similar, but they don't seem to be identical.  Why should I choose one over the other?  Or does it not matter at all?

Comment: gparted seems more robust over all and comes with a live version. Kubunt partition manager works much better sometime a year into 18.04. If you are running Kubuntu then it is great. In Ubuntu I would use G-Parted

Comment: I wouldn't recomend using KDE Partition manager.

Just lost my data while was moving partiotion.


fdisk + dd is the friend

Answer (score 2):

If you've plenty of ram on your machine, use whichever you prefer. KDE Partition Manager uses the Qt5 toolkit, Gparted uses GTK3 (3.x depending on your release) - so if you use a different one to libraries in your unstated machine, you'll just waste memory during use.

Lubuntu for example used `gparted` up to release 18.04 LTS, however later releases use KDE Partition Manager, as it's more memory efficient on the LXQt desktop used by Lubuntu 18.10 and later releases.

With my machines 8GB of ram; I'm not worried which I use (I can afford the memory hit regardless of whether I'm using LXQt (Lubuntu) or XFCE/GNOME (Xubuntu/GNOME).

Comment: I used the examples I did because those desktops are installed on my current *groovy* machine. KDE uses Qt like Lubuntu so it would apply equally, however I don't have `kubuntu-desktop` installed on this box.